# C beginner help : day of week for any given date

Tags: c, date, datetime

The prompt is:
Implement a function that reads in a string containing a textual description of a cal- endar date and that prints out the corresponding day of the week (Monday–Sunday). The two valid input formats for this function are:

mm/dd/yyyy

Example: 03/04/2014
 Output: Tuesday

Month dd, yyyy

Example: March 04, 2014
 Output: Tuesday

where dd is the numeric day, mm is the numeric month, yyyy is the year and Month is the name of the month. All days and months are specified using two digits (i.e. for March, use 03 instead of 3). In the second valid format, there is a single space between Month and dd and between dd, and yyyy.
In order to receive full credit on this task, your program should print out the correct day of the week for any input in a correct format.

**So as of right now i am able to get the correct days for every single day except in the years 2005 2009 2013 2017 etc etc... they are always a day behind, i notice that its going by a trend of every 4 years the days end up 1 day behind. Im not sure whats wrong. is it cause my method of using 365.25 as each year is wrong?**

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int month,day1,day2,totdays,year,dm,dn,leap,rmd;


    printf(" ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&month,&day1,&year);


    if(((year%4==0) && (year%100!=0)) || (year%400==0))
      {
         if(month==1)
            dm=0;

         if(month==2)
            dm=31;

         if(month==3)
            dm=60;

         if(month==4)
            dm=91;

         if(month==5)
            dm=121;

         if(month==6)
            dm=152;

         if(month==7)
            dm=182;

         if(month==8)
            dm=213;

         if(month==9)
            dm=244;

         if(month==10)
            dm=274;

         if(month==11)
            dm=305;

         if(month==12)
            dm=335;
       }
    else
       {
         if(month==1)
            dm=0;

         if(month==2)
            dm=31;

         if(month==3)
            dm=59;

         if(month==4)
            dm=90;

         if(month==5)
            dm=120;

         if(month==6)
            dm=151;

         if(month==7)
            dm=181;

         if(month==8)
            dm=212;

         if(month==9)
            dm=243;

         if(month==10)
            dm=273;

         if(month==11)
            dm=304;

         if(month==12)
            dm=334;
       }


      day2=(year-1970)*(365.25);
      dn=dm+day1;
      totdays=day2+dn;

      rmd=totdays%7;

      if(rmd==5)
        {
           printf("Monday \n");
        }

      if(rmd==6)
        {
           printf("Tuesday \n");
        }

      if(rmd==0)
        {
            printf("Wednesday \n");
        }

      if(rmd==1)
        {
            printf("Thursday \n");
        }

      if(rmd==2)
        {
            printf("Friday \n");
        }

      if(rmd==3)
        {
            printf("Saturday \n");
        }

      if(rmd==4)
        {
            printf("Sunday \n");
        }

      return 0;

}
```

Comment: How strange that all the years giving you trouble are those following a leap year. Look again at your leap year handling.

Comment: i did double check my leap year condition, is it wrong?

Comment: This is more of a math problem. If you can crack the math in it then you have got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1969 wasn't a leap year, 1972 was. When you do

```
day2=(year-1970)*(365.25);
```

to discover how many days off January 1st of year *year* is, you'll count

- 0 days for '70
- 365.25 days for '71
- 730.5 days for '72
- 1095.75 days for '73
- 1461 days for '74

The fractional portion of the floating point calculation is truncated, so day2 isn't going to count the extra day from 02/29/1972 until 01/01/1974, instead of 01/01/1973 as it should.

Put another way, you are making the assumption that 1970 was the first year after a leap year, so a leap day won't be counted until four years later.

Comment: i realized 1970 wasent a leap year, so should it be day2=(year-1973)*(365.25)

Comment: Yes, but then you'll have to fix if/else if chain below to deal with the fact that 1/1/1973 was a Monday.

I've realized you have another issue: For years before 1970 (or 1973 if you make the change you're suggesting) the result will be negative, and rmd=totdays%7; will not behave like you expect.

Comment: ty! it works now.. and i realized that it would be negative if i picked any year prior to whatever year im subtracting with. Couldnt i just do absolute values though?

Comment: The problem is that the % operator in C doesn't really do the modular arithmetic you'd like. (-1) % 7 is -1 instead of (-1) MOD 7 which is 6; this makes more sense if you think of -1 as "the number before 0", in MOD 7 arithmetic counting down from 0 gets you to 6. The good news is that you can fix this pretty easily, if you get a negative result from totdays % 7, just add 7.

Answer (score 0):

The `day2` calculation won't work.  There are 1461 days in every four year period. First you need to compute how many 4 year periods have passed. Then figure out how many days there were to the beginning of the specified year, similar to what you did for the months.

The `year%100` and `year%400` exceptions add a little complexity, but fortunately the year 2000 was a leap year, so the first time you have to deal with that little wrinkle is the year 2100.

Comment: why wont calculations for day2 work? could you give me an example as to how i can do the right calculations?

Comment: It doesn't work because no year has 365.25 days in it. A year either has 365 days or 366 days. A slightly different approach is to compute days assuming all years are 365 days, and then compute the number of leap years, and add that to the total.

Comment: how would i be able to do that in my code? could you show me an example, for example, if i entered in the year 2017 then it would be 2017-1970=47 i dont know how to figure our which of the 47 were leap years.

Comment: Well, it would be every 4th year starting with 1972 (with minor exceptions like the year 2100).

Comment: yea i realized 1970 wasent a leap year but 1972 was, im still not sure how to fix my problem though. :(

Comment: Sometimes it helps to work out examples on a piece of paper. Write down all the years from 1970 to 2000, and then determine the number of leap days for each year by hand. Then see if you can come up with a mathematical formula that matches the pattern that you computed by hand.